# out arguments with not declared variable

Tags: c#, out

I have a method

```
TrySplitStringTwoParts(string data, string separator, out string prefix, out string suffix)
```

it is called in the following way:

```
string data = "x.y", r1,r2;
TrySplitStringTwoParts(data, ".", out r1, out r2)
```

I am not interested to use `r1` ,i.e. it is never used besides this call.
Can I cange the way I call to the `TrySplitStringTwoParts(data, ".", out r1, out r2)` in order not to declare `r1`

Comment: where is the r1 and r2 declared?

Comment: @RonaldEstacion - string data = "x.y", r1,r2;

Comment: How about overloading it?

Comment: Then create an overload without the out r1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that for now. But that is one of the features that will be added in `C# 6`.See the roslyn [Language feature implementation status page](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Feature                 | Example                      | C#   |            
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Declaration expressions | int.TryParse(s, out var x);  | Done |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

So then you will be able to do this:

```
TrySplitStringTwoParts(data, ".", out string r1, out string r2)
```

Ofcourse this will only move the declaration to another place,not declaring the variable is not possible.If you have a `ref`/`out` parameter then you have to declare and provide an argument.If you don't want this argument then maybe you should consider changing your method signature or use method overloading.

Comment: That only allows you to declare the variables in a different place, but you still have to declare them.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. `ref` and `out` arguments must be passed in the call regardless of whether you actually use the variable later on or not.